# Unable to Import parts with Metadata

Tags: c#, metadata, mef, .net-4.5

I'm trying to import parts and include a custom MetadataAttribute, following the imperative model, using .NET 4.5

Below, I've included the simplest of example I can, which illustrates the problem.

When this code is executed, the `Engine` class constructor is called, and passed an empty Enumerator, rather than the two plugins which are clearly part of the project.

At the moment I'm suspecting the PluginMetadata attribute, but I don't see how to get Metadata into the catalog without it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Registration;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = new RegistrationBuilder();
            builder.ForTypesDerivedFrom<IPlugIn>().Export<Lazy<IPlugIn, IPlugInMetadata>>();
            builder.ForType<Engine>().Export();
            var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), builder);
            var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

            var engine = container.GetExport<Engine>();
            engine.Value.Run();

        }
    }

    internal class Engine
    {
        private IEnumerable<Lazy<IPlugIn, IPlugInMetadata>> PlugIns { get; set; }
        public Engine(IEnumerable<Lazy<IPlugIn, IPlugInMetadata>> plugins)
        {
            PlugIns = plugins;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            foreach (var plugIn in PlugIns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Starting {0}", plugIn.Metadata.Name);
                plugIn.Value.Work();
            }
        }
    }

    interface IPlugIn
    {
        void Work();
    }

    interface IPlugInMetadata
    {
        string Name { get; }
    }

    [MetadataAttribute]
    class PlugInMetadataAttribute : ExportAttribute, IPlugInMetadata
    {
        public PlugInMetadataAttribute(string name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        private readonly string name;
        public string Name { get { return name; } }
    }

    [PlugInMetadata("PlugIn1")]
    class PlugIn1 : IPlugIn
    {
        public void Work()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PlugIn 1 working");
        }
    }

    [PlugInMetadata("PlugIn2")]
    class PlugIn2 : IPlugIn
    {
        public void Work()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("PlugIn 2 working");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata interfaces must not have any properties with setters. You should modify the `IPlugInMetadata` interface so its properties won't have any setters, otherwise the composition will fail:

```
interface IPlugInMetadata
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

Also, you should consider making your `PlugInMetadataAttribute` class inherit from `ExportAttribute` rather than `Attribute`. That will allow using this attribute as an export attribute and you won't have to use a `RegistrationBuilder`.

---

**EDIT:** I think I found your problem

When trying to use `ImportMany` in the constructor, you must specify so explicitly, so your constructor should look like this:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public Engine([ImportMany] IEnumerable<Lazy<IPlugIn, IPlugInMetadata>> plugins)
{
    PlugIns = plugins;
}
```

Alternatively, you can choose to import it as a property:

```
[ImportMany]
private IEnumerable<Lazy<IPlugIn, IPlugInMetadata>> PlugIns { get; set; }
```

As a side note, when deriving from `ExportAttribute`, you'd like to include constructors that automatically export your part as `IPlugIn`:

```
[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
class PlugInMetadataAttribute : ExportAttribute, IPlugInMetadata
{
    public PlugInMetadataAttribute()
        : base(typeof(IPlugIn))
    {
    }

    public PlugInMetadataAttribute(string contractName)
        : base(contractName, typeof(IPlugIn))
    {
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Adi I have tried your suggestions which certainly sounded likely.  I've edited my original question with the code updated accordingly.  However the Engine is still not receiving any plugins.  There must be more to the puzzle.

Comment: Perfect --- apparently I can't award the bounty until tomorrow.

Comment: Property injected parts are not available until constructor code has completed so that is why you need constructor injection instead.